# 'List<dynamic>' is not a subtype of type 'List<Water>' in type cast

Tags: flutter, dart

I want to show the sum of data as String, but I am getting an error.

> 'List' is not a subtype of type 'List' in type cast
> At line number 11

I am using Hive for database.

Can you help me fix the error?

```dart
class Home extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: SafeArea(
        child: Container(
          child: Center(
            child: ValueListenableBuilder(
                valueListenable: getBoxValueListeneable(),
                builder: (context, box, _) => Text(
                    sumWater(box.get(formatTimeToString(DateTime.now()))).toString(),
                    style: Theme.of(context).textTheme.headline2)),
          ),
        ),
      ),
      floatingActionButtonLocation: FloatingActionButtonLocation.centerFloat,
      floatingActionButton: FloatingActionButton(
        child: Icon(Icons.add),
        onPressed: () async {
          Navigator.pushNamed(context, '/addWaterBox');
        },
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

use `.cast()` like this

```
void main() {
  List a = [];
  List<String> b;
  
//   b = a; not working
  b = a.cast();
}
```